# Changing the last log length in irssi?

Tags: irssi

Google failed me on this. I'd like to lengthen my lastlog size in irssi. I know that it's possible, since I've managed to do it years ago. I guess its one of those more esoteric commands?

Comment: Oops, realized it already! It's "/set scrollback_lines". The term "scrollback" didn't come to my mind, so I wouldn't find it from Google.

Comment: Great you found the answer yourself. Would you mind posting it as one, so others having the same problem can find it?

Answer (score 2):

```
/set scrollback_lines 500
```

Set history to 500 lines.

```
/set scrollback_time 1day
```

Keeps at least one day even if it exceeds the maximum lines.

And here's the settings page for irssi:
http://irssi.org/documentation/settings